# Deleted Contacts in marketing cloud impacting CRM intergration

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We use the standard connector package (which is up to date)
However we used MC as ET for a while and are only now integrating with CRM (Sales and service)
Currently in MC we delete the contacts as we use email as the primary Key (legacy issues). 
Now that we are ready to integrate contacts and leads from CRM for communications in MC the question(s) will be;

1. For data to MC - as the contacts will recreate if we delete them will this cause duplicates or given its the same ID should we be fine?
2. If we delete contacts and leads in MC it will not delete records in CRM (I've researched this i think we are fine but just checking)
3. For the data back to CRM (such as sends, opens, bounces unsubscribes) if we delete the record in the MC (not just the contact but the records held natively in MC to store the send results such as _bounce, _Open, _Sent) will this delete the MC data stored against contacts and leads records in the CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of data from CRM (Sales Cloud and Service Cloud) to Marketing Cloud as one directional. Data that is bi-directional (Marketing Cloud to CRM) is email tracking data and data updated from Journey activities or AMPscript (create or update Salesforce objects).

To answer your questions:

1. There won’t be duplicates created. Also see number 2 below.
2. You cannot delete records in synchronized data extensions so those contacts cannot be deleted.
3. Again see number 2. Individual Email Results will be created in CRM for tracking data and the data views cannot be deleted of tracking information (unless it is over 6 months old).